# Get a SMS or Push Notification instantly when an email is send to Gmail

Tags: gmail, email, automation, sms, android

I have integrated my business email to be checked via my Gmail account, using the "Check email from other accounts:" option using POP3.

I want to get an instant SMS or push notification on my Android phone when any email is sent to my business email address me@mybusiness.com.

What platforms exist or ideas are there that can do this for free? I want to try and avoid the automation platforms such as Zapier etc and perhaps have some form of app installed on my phone that can trigger the push or SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to settings and tap on yourname @gmail.com:

[image: Your Gmail Account Settings]

Now go to "Manage Labels" and ensure that you have sync turned on for **all** your mail:

[image: Turn on ALL syncs]

That isn't turned on by default.

While you are in the Settings you might as well check to ensure that you didn't accidentally disable the default Notifications ("Manage Notifications").